# No route to host error while login using google plus in PHP

Tags: php, google-plus-signin

I wanted Google plus login in my PHP website. I tried to integrate it from : http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php

When I try to login, It throws error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: No route to host' in /home/thewiref/public_html/mastkids.in/test_google/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /home/thewiref/public_html/mastkids.in/test_google/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php(101): Google_CurlIO->makeRequest(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1 /home/thewiref/public_html/mastkids.in/test_google/src/Google_Client.php(131): Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, NULL) #2 /home/thewiref/public_html/mastkids.in/test_google/index.php(8): Google_Client->authenticate() #3 {main} thrown in /home/thewiref/public_html/mastkids.in/test_google/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php on line 128
```

Same code is working perfect in different domain and server. So what could be issue in this server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Firewall settings and network connectivity to see if you are able to connect to the network.
Try running the following
`<?php
$read = file_get_contents("https://google.com");
echo $read;`
If you are able to see the google page(even if it is distorted).
If not then your system has a network connectivity issue or DNS issues.

Comment: Try disabling the firewall if you own that machine and check the response.